# How to Enlarge JButton Image when MouseOver "Mouse hovers over it"

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jbutton

Pretty much my "Start" button wont enlarge when I hover over it.
Here is my code below any Idea on why it wont? and if could show me an example code that would really help! :)"i'm still pretty new to java too" so thats why example code would help me better thanks in advance!.

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static JButton button;
private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Scroller Runner v0.2.0");

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new Window();
    JButton button = new JButton();
    JTextPane TEXT = new JTextPane();
    BufferedImage buttonIcon;
    button = new JButton(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\GOULDEN\\Desktop\\MENU_START.png"));
    button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button.setBounds(490, 250, 300, 75);
    button.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    button.addMouseListener(null);

    frame.setSize(1280, 720);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\GOULDEN\\Desktop\\MAIN_MENU.png")))));
    frame.pack();
    frame.add(button);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    button.setBounds(550, 300, 300, 75);
    this.repaint();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered trying to use [`JButton#setRolloverIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverIcon(javax.swing.Icon))?

Comment: i see lot of problems in your code 
1) you have `extend` `jframe` but you create `new frame()` 
2)you call `button.addMouseListener(null);`

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen setContentPane() called on a JLabel

Comment: 3) `frame.setContentPane(new JLabel())`

Comment: do you at least get the expected interface??

Comment: @BScody consider using a JPanel with an appropriate layout manager as your contentPane and add your other components to that JPanel

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code works for me.

As you want to change the size only `setSize()` is better for this.

```
    button.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                
            button.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);                
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
button.setBounds(550, 300, 300, 75);
```

with:

```
button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try the attached Code its work for me**

```
   private JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();

   @Override
   public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    myFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                    myFrame.initialize(instance);

                    myFrame.setLocation(instance.nMainPanelXPosition,instance.nMainPanelYPosition);
                    myFrame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    myFrame.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
      }
```